# Is a lookup table a form of hash table?

Tags: c++, c, language-agnostic, hashtable, terminology

I am trying to see if I am conceptually correct here . .

If I'm trying to avoid having to compute a computationally expensive `someExpensiveFun(x)` for every element in an array of floating point data `x`, say bounded to values between zero and one, one can first precompute the output of the expensive function and store it in a table . . .

```
for (int nn = 0; nn < 1000; ++nn)
{
    float tmp = ((float)nn) / 1000.f;
    lookup[nn] = someExpensiveFun(tmp);
}
```

Then in the main body of performance critical code I can use . . .

```
y = lookup[(int)floor(x*1000.f)];
```

Is it conceptually correct (and not an abuse of terminology) to call `lookup` a form of hash table and `x*1000` the associated hashing function?

Comment: I would say no, but not sure what others think.

Comment: It's the other way around. I'd rather say that a hash table is a type of lookup table.

Comment: `(int) floor(x * 1000.f)` could be considered the hash function, sure. @H2CO3 is correct in stating a hash table is merely a form of look-up table.

Comment: If a hash table is a type of lookup table, what specific feature makes a hash table more than a lookup table?

Comment: @learnvst there are several types of hash tables, but the key (pun intended) is that they transform the key using some hash function into an index. In this case, you use a minimal perfect hash function that avoids collisions, so this translates to `array[hash(key)]` -- much like your `lookup[x * 1000]` for x [0, 1).

Comment: Btw, I take it that the derivative of `someExpensiveFun` has small absolute values everywhere between 0 and 1, so that rounding down to 0.001 gives a good approximation ;-)

Comment: @SteveJessop Linear hashing function (be careful what I say there) was just used to exemplify, nit-picker ;P

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Personally I'd say it's an abuse of terminology. It lacks properties that people naturally expect from a hash table, notably the ability to do something about non-equal keys with equal hashes. And I'm pretty sure your "hash function" has to be considered as `floor(x*1000.f)` or `(int)floor(x*1000.f)`, not just `x*1000.f`.

Hash tables also normally can accept as key any value of their key type, rather than just values in a range, but maybe I'm being too picky there. I wouldn't call an otherwise-normal hash table that didn't allow `NaN` as a key, "not a hash table".

It has some properties in common with hash tables (a non-injective function that maps keys to integers, said integers used as an index in an array). If someone wants to decide that those two things together characterize "a hash table", OK, good luck to them, it's a hash table :-)

Comment: Agreed but perfect hashing doesn't need collision resolution ;-)

Comment: @oldrib: yeah, I thought of that and thought I didn't need to mention it. Serve me right ;-) A perfect hash deals with collisions by *choosing a different hash in the first place*! It also has the property of working only for selected values from the key type.

Comment: Thanks for a considered response +1. I'm trying to find the key feature that makes the distinction. I cannot find a concise definition.

Comment: @leanvst: indeed, that can be the way with data structures and even algorithms when you lump together variants under a common name. I may not be able to precisely define "a hash table" or "a quick sort", but I know one when I see one.

Answer (score 5):

No, it is not conceptually correct to call a lookup table a hash table: in your case a lookup table is a simple array. Calling something a hash table implies certain behavior in cases when the hash function is not perfect (i.e. in the presence of hash collisions); arrays have none of this behavior, so calling this a "hash lookup" would likely mislead your listeners or readers.

In general, any kind of associative storage, including hash tables, various trees, and so on, can be used to perform lookup operations. In your case, the index of the array is associated with the value stored at that index, letting you look up the value in constant time.

Comment: I'd have to disagree. The OP is arguably correct in believing it can be considered a hash table. Hash tables associate an input key with a unique output value (i.e. they are *mappings*) -- in this case, each `x` is associated with `someExpensiveFun(x)` by the use of a minimal perfect hash function.

Comment: @oldrinb I guess you can call an array index a "minimal perfect hash function", although I think this complicates things a great deal. Calling it "an array lookup" gets the point across much better.

Answer (score 3):

You have it backwards. A hash table can always be used as a slow substitute for an array, but an array cannot be used as a substitute for a hash table (unless some very strict preconditions are met).

In your case the lookup doesn't even produce the same results as the calculation, only a close approximation. A true hash table would differentiate between different inputs that hashed to the same index.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if you accept Wikipedia's definition of [hash table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table).  Quoting from that definition:

```
Ideally, the hash function should map each possible key to a unique slot index,
but this ideal is rarely achievable in practice (unless the hash keys are fixed;
i.e. new entries are never added to the table after it is created).
```

You have chosen an array because the [domain of your function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_of_a_function) is well defined and relatively small and lends itself to be the index of the array - the domain of the function has an [onto](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surjective_function) mapping to the index of the array.  You can think of the index as the `key` to the `hash table` and the function output is the associated value.

Answer (score 1):

You can substitute all lookup tables by hash tables, but you can't substitute all hash tables by lookup tables. So yes, a lookup table can be considered to be a special form of a hash table, and a hash table can be considered to be a general form of a lookup table.

In a similar way, a list can be considered to be a special form of a 2D table (with a single column).

However, we are talking about software here. There are a gazillion different solutions to a given problem, and a gazillion different possibilities to build your data structures. For the example, with static size or dynamic growth, with required unique entries or with collision handling, with a fixed or a configurable hash function, etc. There are a lot of ways between a plain lookup table and a full hash table, without a clear border where you could say here it is this, but there it has become that.

However (again), when a specific data structure proves to be useful, it usually gets its own name. As was said here, with such a name there are associated expectations about the functionality. There may even be a strict definition about the required minimum functionality. If you want your code to be readable by others, you better stick to the known terms. Thus you should call your lookup table a lookup table, even though technically it is a special form of a hash table.